# Ajax request to django view not returning response

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm making a website where I want to load user submitted comments on elements and I want to be able to dynamically display them and not have the webpage have to load them all at once. so I setup this ajax request function:

```
function loadcomments(){
   $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/getcomments/',
        data: {
            'identifier': {{ identifier }}
            'begin': 0,
            'end': 30
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.comments);
        }
   });
};
```

And a view to respond to that request:

```
def obtain_comments(request, *args, **kwargs):
    begin = kwargs.get('begin');
    end = kwargs.get('end');
    comments = end - begin
    all_before = Comment.objects.order_by('-uploaded')[:end]
    data = {
        'comments': all_before.order_by('uploaded')[:comments]
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

But I'm not getting a response. I'm not seeing any errors inside the browser console, however in the django runserver terminal I see:

```
Internal Server Error: /ajax/getcomments/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/vidmiotest/player/views.py", line 64, in obtain_comments
    comments = end - begin
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

or if I set begin and end to a fixed value instead of kwargs:

```
Internal Server Error: /ajax/getcomments/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/vidmiotest/player/views.py", line 67, in obtain_comments
    'comments': all_before.order_by('uploaded')[:comments]
  File "/home/trie/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1012, in order_by
    "Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken."
AssertionError: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.
```

I tried removing the element Identifier from the 'obtain_comments' view so I would get any comments in the database. I'm however expecting the view to respond 1 comment I manually inserted into the database.

inside `urls.py` i defined the url like this:

```
path('ajax/getcomments/', obtain_comments),
```

Why am I not geting a response?

Comment: So do you know why you're getting `NoneType` for `end` and/or `begin`?

Comment: No that's part of the question... I know the request gets to the view but i don't understand the errors that occure then

Answer (score 2):

`args` and `kwargs` in a view are for arguments that are passed in the URL and captured in the URL pattern. You don't have any of these; your Ajax is sending the values in the GET querystring. So you need to get them from `request.GET`. Also note, the values will be strings, so you need to convert them to ints.

```
begin = int(request.GET['begin'])
end = int(request.GET['end'])
```

The other error is explained in the error message itself; you can't order after slicing. You should do it before.